# Laravel elixir combine some file, but minify just some of them

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

Iv've got three files: a.min.js, b.min.js and c.js

I would like to minify c.js, and then combine a + b + c into a unique file using laravel elixir. Is it possible? Now I'm using this script:

```
elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
            .webpack('app.js')
            .combine([
                'resources/assets/js/plugins/a.min.js',
                'resources/assets/js/plugins/b.min.js',
                'resources/assets/js/plugins/c.js'
            ], 'public/js/plugins/xxx.js');
});
```

But obviously c.js is not minified.

Answer (score 0):

In order to minify a file you have to call gulp with the `--production` parameter.

It's only possible to minify all or nothing.

Comment: It is not possible to minifiy it in a temporary location, and then combine it with the already minified files?

Comment: AFAIK no, because the minification is the last step.